How can I use distinct(..., .keep_all = TRUE) but specify which row to keep?
Say I have the following:
> df
  x y z
1 A 1 o
2 A 0 m
3 A 1 g 

And I want to keep unique observations without considering a particular column, such as:
> dplyr::distinct(df, dplyr::across(-z), .keep_all = TRUE)
  x y z
1 A 1 o
2 A 0 m

But I am only interested in rows where z == g (or one of a set of values).
How can I specify, that if there exists a duplicate row, which of the two rows to keep ?
I have not tried any solutions because I cannot find any suggestions in the dplyr docs (or on Stack Overflow).

You can use the filter() function from dplyr to first filter the rows where z == 'g' (or any other condition you want), and then use distinct() to remove duplicates. Here's how you can do it:
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(z == 'g') %>%
  distinct(across(-z), .keep_all = TRUE)

This will first filter the rows where z is 'g', and then remove duplicates without considering the z column. If there are duplicate rows with z == 'g, it will keep the first one.
If you want to keep the last duplicate instead of the first one, you can add the slice_max() function:
df %>%
  filter(z == 'g') %>%
  group_by(across(-z)) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

This will group the data by all columns except z, and then keep the last row in each group. The ungroup() function is used to remove the grouping afterwards.

I might've phrased my question poorly, but if I understand correctly, this will then mean that I won't find all the duplicates. Because then my dataframe won't have row 1, which I want to compare with row 3, which are duplicates (ignoring column z), and then drop the duplicate that has o for column z instead of dropping the row which has g in column z.

You could tag the ones you'd like to keep, e.g. z %in% c("g", "h", "i", ...), sort them to the top of each x, y group, then slice the first one in each x, y group:
(Assumes you only want 1 per x, y group.)
library(dplyr)

tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  "A", 1, "o",
  "A", 0, "m",
  "A", 1, "g"
) |> 
  mutate(keep = if_else(z %in% c("g"), 1, NA)) |> 
  arrange(x, y, keep) |> 
  slice_head(n = 1, by = c(x, y))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   x         y z      keep
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A         0 m        NA
#> 2 A         1 g         1

Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.1.0

Using base R. Remove duplicated rows (with regards to all columns except z) but first remove rows with df$z != g.
cols <- setdiff(names(df), "z")
df[order(df$z != "g"), ][!duplicated(df[cols]), ]
  x y z
3 A 1 g
1 A 1 o

Where df <- data.frame(x = "A", y = c(1,0,1), z = c("o", "m", "g")).
